# convert date string to momentjs object - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I have prop timestamp validation for object, so that it must be an object. when i wrote the test it is failing because momentJs returns string on what i'm doing. I searched alot but couldn't find any thing useful. here is my test case:

```js
console.log((moment(moment().format('LL') + ' 11:45').utc().format()));
```

It returns a string

```js
2018-09-15T06:45:00Z
```

I want the same thing but in object of moment. can any one guide me through this

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.format()` will just give you a moment object?

I don't really get what you try to do here

`console.log((moment(moment().format('LL') + ' 11:45').utc().format()));`

Why would you format to string then wrap into moment object then format to string again?